# SQL Server 2008, how to check if multi records exist in the DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I have 3 tables:

- recipe:

  - id, name
- ingredient:

  - id, name
- recipeingredient:

  - id, recipeId, ingredientId, quantity

Every time, a customer creates a new recipe, I need to check the `recipeingredient` table to verify if this recipe exists or not.  If `ingredientId` and `quantity` are exactly the same, I will tell the customer the recipe already exists.  Since I need to check multiple rows, need help to write this query.

Comment: How do you represent the new recipe?  Is it in the same tables, in temprorary tables, in memory?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am assuming it's a form post...but good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing your ingredients and quantities, you can do something like this:

```
select recipeId as ExistingRecipeID
from recipeingredient
where (ingredientId = 1 and quantity = 1)
    or (ingredientId = 8 and quantity = 1)
    or (ingredientId = 13 and quantity = 1)
group by recipeId
having count(*) = 3 --must match # of ingeredients in WHERE clause
```

Answer (score 2):

I originally thought that the following query would find pairs of recipes that have exactly the same ingredients:

```
select ri1.recipeId, ri2.recipeId
from RecipeIngredient ri1 full outer join
     RecipeIngredient ri2
     on ri1.ingredientId = ri2.ingredientId and
        ri1.quantity = ri2.quantity and
        ri1.recipeId < ri2.recipeId
group by ri1.recipeId, ri2.recipeId
having count(ri1.id) = count(ri2.id) and   -- same number of ingredients
       count(ri1.id) = count(*) and        -- all r1 ingredients are present
       count(*) = count(ri2.id)            -- all r2 ingredents are present
```

However, this query doesn't count things correctly, because the mismatches don't have the right pairs of ids.  Alas.

The following *does* do the correct comparison.  It counts the ingredients in each recipe before the join, so this value can just be compared on all matching rows.

```
select ri1.recipeId, ri2.recipeId
from (select ri.*, COUNT(*) over (partition by recipeid) as numingredients
      from @RecipeIngredient ri
     ) ri1 full outer join
     (select ri.*, COUNT(*) over (partition by recipeid) as numingredients
      from @RecipeIngredient ri
     ) ri2
     on ri1.ingredientId = ri2.ingredientId and
        ri1.quantity = ri2.quantity and
        ri1.recipeId < ri2.recipeId
group by ri1.recipeId, ri2.recipeId
having max(ri1.numingredients) = max(ri2.numingredients) and
       max(ri1.numingredients) = count(*)
```

The `having` clause guarantees that each recipe that the same number of ingredients, and that the number of matching ingredients is the total.  This time, I've tested it on the following data:

```
insert into @recipeingredient select 1, 1, 1
insert into @recipeingredient select 1, 2, 10
insert into @recipeingredient select 2, 1, 1
insert into @recipeingredient select 2, 2, 10
insert into @recipeingredient select 2, 3, 10
insert into @recipeingredient select 3, 1, 1
insert into @recipeingredient select 4, 1, 1
insert into @recipeingredient select 4, 3, 10
insert into @recipeingredient select 5, 1, 1
insert into @recipeingredient select 5, 2, 10
```

If you have a new recipe, you can modify this query to just look for the recipe in one of the tables (say ri1) using an additional condition on the `on` clause.

If you place the ingredients in a temporary table, you can substitute one of these tables, say ri1, with the new table.

Comment: @TimLehner . . . Can you elaborate on the error or problem with the data?

Comment: Sure, just try it with my answer's data (which is essentially the same direction as yours). Then change a quantity. Or add/remove a row.  Your `group by` might actually be masking any differences between recipes.

Comment: I run it, and it says that recipes 1 and 2 have the same ingredients.  It is doing the results pairwise, so this shows up twice as 1 and 2 and also as 2 and 1.  I am fixing the answer to prevent this.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't more clear.  This seems to return the same thing no matter what I make the ingredients.  Regardless of the ingredients I set, if I have two recipes, it will always return a row with `1, 2`

Comment: @TimLehner . . . Ooh, a hard problem.  I don't usually get confused on full outer joins, but I did.  The revised version does work.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this to find if you have a duplicate:

```
-- Setup test data
declare @recipeingredient table (
      id int not null primary key identity
    , recipeId int not null
    , ingredientId int not null
    , quantity int not null
)
insert into @recipeingredient select 1, 1, 1
insert into @recipeingredient select 1, 2, 10
insert into @recipeingredient select 2, 1, 1
insert into @recipeingredient select 2, 2, 10

-- Actual Query
if exists (
    select *
    from @recipeingredient old
        full outer join @recipeingredient new
            on old.recipeId != new.recipeId         -- Different recipes
            and old.ingredientId = new.ingredientId -- but same ingredients
            and old.quantity = new.quantity         -- and same quantities
    where old.id is null    -- Match not found
        or new.id is null   -- Match not found
)
begin
    select cast(0 as bit) as IsDuplicateRecipe
end
else begin
    select cast(1 as bit) as IsDuplicateRecipe
end
```

Since this is really only searching for a duplicate, you might want to substitute a temp table or [pass a table variable](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/168) for the "new" table.  This way you wouldn't have to insert the new records before doing your search.  You could also insert into the base tables, wrap the whole thing in a transaction and rollback based upon the results.